# Limit counterexample for infinite union

Tags: real-analysis, limits

It is well known that if a function has the same limit on finitely many sets, then the limit exists on the union of those sets. (just choose the minimal delta). I am trying to find a counterexample to the case where we are dealing with infinitely many sets.

Construct a real function $f$ and subsets $A_1,A_2,A_3\dots$ be sets such that $0$ is a limit point of each of the $A_n$ and $\cup_nA_n=\mathbb{R}$. Satisfying $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$ for each $x\in A_n$ for each of the $n=1,2\dots$. However $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)\ne 0$. That is the limit only holds when we approach $0$ through our individual chosen sets.

The way I think it is to be done, is if each $\delta_n$ (as in the limit definition) get arbitrary small thus there is no minimum non zero delta that work for all the sets.

I think the best function to use is $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ as its the only thing that has no limit at $0$ but has arbitrary many values of $f(x)=0$. However I have no idea how to build the sets based on this.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different version, but this is what I would suggest:

For every prime number $p$ we define
$$X_{p}=\{p^{-n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$
and define $X_{0}=\mathbb{R}\setminus\bigcup_{p\text{ prime }}X_{p}$. Note that these sets satisfy the condition stated. We define
$$f(x):=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x\in X_{0}\\e^{\frac{\log(x)}{\log(p)}}&\text{ if } x\in X_{p}\end{cases}$$
Note that in $X_{p}$ we have that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(p^{-n})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{-n}=0.$$ But if we let $(p_{n})$ be the sequence of prime numbers we find $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(p_{n})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{-1}=e^{-1}.$$